# How to remove a child node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to remove city node having value that I get from `Request.QueryString["removect"]` and under a specific user id say, `<user Id="4/29/2015 6:11:34 PM">`.

```
<Users>
   <user Id="4/28/2015 11:29:44 PM">
    <city>Moga</city>
    <city>Rupnagar</city>
    <city>Fatehgarh Sahib</city>
</user>
  <user Id="4/29/2015 10:59:06 AM">
    <city>Bathinda</city>
    <city>Pathankot</city>
  </user>
  <user Id="4/29/2015 6:11:34 PM">
    <city>Pathankot</city>
    <city>Tarn Taran</city>

  </user>
</Users>
```

The code I'm using to accomplish this is as follows:

```
xmlDocument.Descendants("user").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == usrCookieId)
 .Elements("city")
 .Where(x => (string)x.Value ==Request.QueryString["removect"]).Remove();
```

The code executes but nothing happens.

Comment: Of course nothing happens. You're creating a temporary object and removing stuff from it. You aren't assigning it or anything.

Comment: how can i accomplish my goal to remove the appropriate node

Comment: try .equals and ignore case, show us more code how are reading the xml and stuff. check xmlDocument.Descendants("user").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == usrCookieId)
 .Elements("city") count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

I have started with `city` as you can see, then with its parent i.e. `user` filtering your condition and since `x` consists of city elements we can filter it directly. Now, I am using `First` to fetch only the first matching element, once we have that `city` node all we need to use is `Remove`.

```
XDocument xmlDocument= XDocument.Load("YourXMLFile");
xmlDocument.Descendants("city").First(x => (string)x.Parent.Attribute("Id") == usrCookieId 
           && (string)x == Request.QueryString["removect"]).Remove();
xmlDocument.Save("YourXMLFilePath");
```

Comment: "Try this" is not a good answer.  That's at least what I'm told.

Comment: For me, the original code in the question works just fine. No modification needed. Probably the parameters simply do not match anything?

Comment: @MatthewFrontino yet the author of the response has 7.3K rep

Comment: @Rahul i tried but its not working. it just executed but removed nothing

Comment: @MatthewFrontino - Yep Bro, Just have patience for few minutes as everyone here including Sir Jon Skeet updates his answer after posting.

Comment: @AnilSharma - Have you saved the `xmlDocument`? By calling the save method and mentioning the XML file?

Comment: Nope ! Sorry, it just working now. I forgot. m a newbie in Linq to xml. Can you please refer me to a good book or tutorial of it.

Comment: I studied it from my Fav book - `C# in Nutshell` and later grew with practice :)